# Como pasar query de sql a entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

En sql usualmente realizaba la sgte consulta para obtener un código que iba incrementando de acuerdo al ultimo registro que obtenia de una tabla.

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PRE_COD), 0) + 1 FROM TBL_PRESUPUESTO
```

Pero como aplicaría el select isnull en ef o cual seria la manera idónea que arroje el mismo?.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varios días de intento adjunto lo que me soluciono el problema y me visualiza el código como lo necesita el cliente.

```
 public void OnGet(int idActPac)
        {
          var Cod_Pac = 0;
            String TempCodPac = null;
            var Ultimo_Paciente = (from t in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                   orderby t.PAC_CODIGO
                                   select t).LastOrDefault();
            if (Ultimo_Paciente != null)
            {
                Cod_Pac = (Ultimo_Paciente.PAC_CODIGO != null) ?
                       Convert.ToInt32(Ultimo_Paciente.PAC_CODIGO) + 1 :
                       1;
                if (Cod_Pac < 10)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("0000", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
                else if (Cod_Pac >= 10 && Cod_Pac <= 11)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("000", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
                else if (Cod_Pac > 10 && Cod_Pac < 100)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("000", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
                else if (Cod_Pac >= 100 && Cod_Pac <=101)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("00", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
                else if (Cod_Pac > 100 && Cod_Pac < 1000)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("00", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
                else if (Cod_Pac >= 1000 && Cod_Pac <= 1001)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("0", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
                else if (Cod_Pac > 1000 && Cod_Pac <= 9999)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("0", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
                else if (Cod_Pac > 9999 && Cod_Pac < 99999)
                {
                    TempCodPac = String.Concat("", Convert.ToString(Cod_Pac));
                }
            }
            MODEL_PACIENTE = new PACIENTE
            {
                PAC_CODIGO = TempCodPac,
                PAC_FECHA_NAC = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5),
                Genero_Lista = _lPacienteGen.GetGenero(_context),
                Comuna_Lista = _lComuna.GetComuna(_context),
                Odontologo_Lista = _lOdontologo.GetOdontologo(_context),
                PAC_COD_ODONT = "00000"
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cod = 1;

var presupuesto = (from t in tblPresupuesto
                   orderby t.pre_cod
                   select t).LastOrDefault();

if(presupuesto != null)
{
   cod = (presupuesto.pre_cod != null) ?
          presupuesto.pre_cod + 1 :
          1;
}
```

Hacemos una consulta **Linq** donde ordenamos todos los presupuestos por su código **ascendentemente**, y obtenemos mediante la **función** **LastOrDefault**, el último presupuesto, que de no ser **nulo** sería el que tiene mayor código ya que se ordenó **ascendentemente**.

Posteriormente preguntamos si la **variable presupuesto** no es **nula**, de no ser **nula** se pregunta usando el **operador ternario ?:** si el código de ese presupuesto no es **nulo**, de no ser **nulo** obtenemos el código de este presupuesto aumentado en **1** y lo guardamos en la **variable cod**, de ser **nulo** pues le damos a la **variable cod** el valor **1**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

using System.Linq;

Comment: La consulta funciona sin problema alguno y me trae el ultimo registro pero al momento de sumar me arroja 0000100001 ,con lo cual no estaría realizando la suma correctamente cabe mencionar que son de tipo string para colocarlo en el formato 00001

Comment: Me estas diciendo q pre_cod es un string?

Comment: Si correcto , lo hago de tipo string para anteponer primero los 0 , debido al pedido del cliente que lo requiere asi

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128234/japv entra aqui